# Can damage over time effects crit?

Tags: diablo-iii

I've been using a Witch Doctor build that uses Haunt and Locust Swarm, and I've noticed that my damage varies really widely sometimes. Can these spells "crit"? Is that determined on cast or per tick? How can you tell if it crits? Can a non-crit re-cast override a critical existing DoT effect?

How do Crit Chance and Crit Damage affect DoT skills?

Comment: Turn on "Damage numbers" in game options. White numbers will then mean normal hits, and yellow numbers will mean crits. It definitely is not per cast, but I am not sure if individual ticks crit.

Comment: @OrcJMR Damage numbers are on; all numbers for DoT effects are always white, but they don't always do the same damage, which is why I am wondering about whether they're "invisibly" critting.

Comment: Hm, judging by related questions offered by the site, almost everything, if not absolutely everything, crits. This may be closed as a dupe :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes, DoT spells can crit in Diablo 3.**

Here is a [link to some research](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5911881247), that shows the following facts:

- DoTs can crit, but they display as white, not yellow.
- Some DoTs crit per tick, i.e., each tick can crit individually.
- Some DoTs crit per cast, i.e., the whole spell can crit, making all ticks higher.
- Some spells that jump to new targets recalculate whether they crit when they jump.

There is a list of spells tested in the thread: http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5911881247

Comment: not all DoTs crit as white now.  For instance, the new 2.0 fire walkers crit as yellow, so does Disintegrate.

Comment: What about if I get a crit Haunt and then re-cast Haunt. Can that un-crit-ify the DoT effect that's already placed, or will it just extend the duration of the higher DPS version?

Comment: @StrixVaria Per my understanding, when you re-cast Haunt, it will reroll to see if it crits, and then the new result will be applied. However I do not play a Witch Doctor, so I cannot test.